# how to convert Linq results into string[] ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am selecting data from a Datatable using Linq. Selection will be a column and requirement is functions should return `string[]`. I am not getting how to do convert results in to `string[]`.

Please guide, below is my code:

```
 public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
 {
  if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Dir"] == null)
  {
   return null;
  }

  DataTable dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Dir"];
  var details = from addresses in dt.AsEnumerable()
      where SqlMethods.Like(prefixText, prefixText + "%") || SqlMethods.Like(prefixText, "%" + prefixText + "%")
      select addresses["Details"];



  return details.tol;

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each item in `details` is already a string simply use `IEnumerable<T>.ToArray()`:

```
return details.ToArray();
```

If you need to convert it first (in my example I am using `ToString()`), you can use `Select` to project each item to a string:

```
return details.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Oded, I am sorry I am not much aware of lambda expressions and Linq. Plese guide where I should use this code ? Thanks once agian.

Comment: @haansi - I have only written the last return statement of your function.

Comment: Oded here is an error: Error 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @haansi - have you added a `using System.Linq;` declaration to your CS file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure `ToArray` exists on the resulting object from the query, but if it does you could try:

```
return details.ToArray();
```

If that doesn't work try creating a list of it first:

```
return details.ToList().ToArray();
```

Comment: Under what scenarios would the `details.ToList().ToArray()` workaround be required? Not saying you're wrong, but I can't think of any.

Comment: I'm not sure if IEnumerable has the `ToArray` extension... but most likely it has.